# REST API: Limit Read Permissions for Default Endpoints

Tags: wp-query, permissions, rest-api

What is the best way to limit read access for certain endpoints? (we're assuming I already have an authentication method in place) For example, I have a custom post type 'resume', which is registered to the default endpoint /resume . Resumes should only be viewed by their authors and not the public. I don't want to register a custom endpoint just to have this capability.

I tried using this filter: `apply_filters( "rest_{$this->post_type}_query", $args, $request );` which is on the REST hooks reference [here](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/hooks/).

Here's my code:

```
function protect_resumes($args, $request) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'resume',
        'author'    => get_current_user_id(),
    );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'rest_resume_query', 'protect_resumes', 25, 2 );
```

This works fine for the /resume list endpoint BUT if I type any resume id (ex. /resume/123), I can still see that user's resume.

Thanks!